# JDO not saving object

Tags: jdo

I have a class `Answer`, and when I do `pm.MakePersistent` on an object of that class it doesn't show up in the database.  No exception is thrown or anything.

When I do `pm.MakePersistent` on other classes, they properly show up in the database.  Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the log of whichever implementation you're using would tell you